What happens if two reviewers have incompatible recommendations for a paper?
I submitted a paper to an IOP journal (classical and quantum gravity) two or three months back and two reviewers were assigned. One of them was ok with the paper and recommended it for publication but the other posed some questions. After some moderate revisions considering their comments the second reviewer said their key concern with the paper is unanswered and hence did not recommend it for publication.
However, the editor said that the reports are positive and asked for some minor revisions before further consideration. FYI, we did answer the referee’s key concern politely saying that they are incorrect. However, I cannot understand the editor’s meaning. Do they mean that the paper is accepted even when one of the referee’s has rejected it? What happens if two reviewers have incompatible recommendations for a paper?

The title sounds like two reviewers have contradicting requests. The question state, you replied to one reviewer's request and he is not satisfied.

@usr1234567 Originally I thought the same thing, but reading the question and allowing for the possibility of English not being a first language, I think it's a reasonable title if we interpret "recommendation" as "recommendation to the editor on whether to publish" and not "recommendation to the author for improvements on a manuscript", which is a standard way to use the word "recommendation" in a peer review context.

Keep in mind that a paper can be rejected even if all reviews are strongly positive and even if the handling editor recommends acceptance. (This has happened to me several times as an editor.)

The editor decides
As you yourself said, the reviewers only make recommendations; it is always the editor who makes the ultimate decision to accept or reject.  So it is entirely possible for a paper to be accepted even if some (or even all) of the reviews recommend rejection, or vice versa.
If the reviews make incompatible recommendations, then it is up to the editor to consider all of them and make a decision.  Necessarily the decision will disagree with at least one of the reviews.

I have heard that occasionally, in cases where there is a "split decision" among the reviewers, a journal will solicit another review to "break the tie".  I don't know how common this is, though.

@MichaelSeifert My impression is that it's become a lot less common as editors have found it difficult to find reviewers and journals have prioritized a faster turnaround time; they'd instead like editors to make a decision with what they have.

I +1'ed Nate Eldredge's answer, and will add that some journals might have a policy where if an editor decides to accept a paper with a reject review remaining, another editorial board member must be consulted (leading to a double decision). I don't know if there is such a policy for Classical and Quantum Gravity.
Note your paper is not accepted. The decision is 'minor revision'. Papers can be rejected after minor revisions. But your paper is not rejected either; there is still a chance it will be accepted.
You might also be interested in Why do editors sometimes accept a paper even if a reviewer recommends rejection?

Thanks for the answer. It seems that an editorial board member is also included as we have received a comment from he/she indicating that we did not satisfactorily answered the referee. However, we sent a new letter stating our answer explicitly. So based on your comment, now the editor and the member would decide for our paper; am I right?

@TheFyziker The editorial board member handling your paper is usually also the "editor" in this context. Journals have lots of editorial board members. It's possible a second editorial board member will be involved, but given that it's only at revision stage, it's highly unlikely they're involved already. It might happen later, if the decision turns into 'reject' and the current editor accepts anyway.


the editor said that the reports are positive and asked for some minor revisions before further consideration.

This is the only thing that really matters since (as others have said) the editor is the one who makes the decision. "Before further consideration" means that the paper is not accepted, but the editor will make a decision after seeing the revisions they want. So, make the revisions requested by the editor and write a response explaining the changes you made. You could explain why you disagree with Referee 2, but it sounds like the editor is not asking you to do this. There's a little bit of a strategic decision in whether or not to include that in your response, since you want to address the referee reports, but you don't want to come across as repetitive or combative if you have already convinced the editor of your position. I can't really say without more context, but if you have an advisor or trusted colleague you can always ask them for advice. Based on what the editor has said, it sounds like you have a good chance of the paper being accepted. Good luck.
